# Floating Point Arithmetic error

Tags: python, floating-point, double, precision, ieee-754

I'm using the following function to approximate the derivative of a function at a point:

```
def prime_x(f, x, h):

    if not f(x+h) == f(x) and not h == 0.0: 
        return (f(x+h) - f(x)) / h
    else:
        raise PrecisionError
```

As a test I'm passing `f` as `fx` and `x` as 3.0. Where `fx` is:

```
def fx(x):

    import math
    return math.exp(x)*math.sin(x)
```

Which has `exp(x)*(sin(x)+cos(x))` as derivative. Now, according to Google and to my calculator

`exp(3)*(sin(3)+cos(3)) = -17.050059`.

So far so good. But when I decided to test the function with small values for `h` I got the following:

```
print prime_x(fx, 3.0, 10**-5)
-17.0502585578
print prime_x(fx, 3.0, 10**-10)
-17.0500591423
 print prime_x(fx, 3.0, 10**-12)
-17.0512493014
print prime_x(fx, 3.0, 10**-13)
-17.0352620898
print prime_x(fx, 3.0, 10**-16)
__main__.PrecisionError: Mantissa is 16 digits
```

Why does the error increase when h decreases (after a certain point)? I was expecting the contrary until `f(x+h)` was equal to `f(x)`.

Comment: If you find yourself writing: `if not a and not b: do this` `else: do that` you can usually write: `if a or b: do that` `else: do this` and it won't hurt other people's brain to read.

Comment: @askewchan, in this case the advice is even better, since you can drop the `else` entirely. You handle the error case in the `if`, then handle the normal case once it passes.

Comment: [Click here for usable advice ;-)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Practical_considerations_using_floating_point_arithmetic)

Comment: This should not have been marked as a duplicate; the errors induced by numeric differentiation are not the same as the errors in the purported duplicate problem. There is an entire field of mathematics for studying what happens when numerical approximation is used for calculations, called numerical analysis. It is not reasonable to simply lump all numerical accuracy issues into a category of “floating point is inaccurate”. These issues are studied, there are approaches for addressing them, there are interesting properties and patterns in the errors, and they are not all the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Floating-point arithmetic (and integer arithmetic and fixed-point arithmetic) has a certain granularity: Values can only change by a certain step size. For IEEE-754 64-bit binary format, that step size is about 2<sup>–52</sup> times the value (about 2.22•10<sup>–16</sup>). That is very small for physical measurements.

However, when you make *h* very small, the difference between f(*x*) and f(*x*+*h*) is not very large compared to the step size. The difference can only be an integral multiple of the step size.

When the derivative is *d*, the change in f(*x*) is about *h*•*d*. Even if you calculate f(*x*) and f(*x*+*h*) as well as possible in the floating-point format, the measured value of their difference must be a multiple of the step size *s*, so it must be round(*h*•*d*/*s*)•*s*, where round(*y*) is *y* rounded to the nearest integer. Clearly, as you make *h* smaller, *h*•*d*/*s* is smaller, so the effect of rounding it to an integer is relatively larger.

Another way of looking at this is that, for a given f(*x*), there is a certain amount of error in calculating values around f(*x*). As you make *h* smaller, f(*x*+*h*)–f(*x*) gets smaller, but the error stays the same. Therefore, the error increases relative to *h*.

Answer (score 6):

When you subtract two numbers that are almost the same, the result has much less precision than either of the inputs. This reduces the precision of the overall result.

Suppose you have the following two numbers, good to 15 decimal places:

```
  1.000000000000001
- 1.000000000000000
= 0.000000000000001
```

See what happened? The result only has one good digit.

Comment: I always find it illustrative to demonstrate stuff like `1.0 - 1e-33 == 1.0`.  Even though mathematically this isn't `True`, python thinks it is `True` because there isn't enough precision to represent that small difference between those numbers.  In this case, you could have a wide range of `h` which produce the same (or very similar) results when subtracting.  When you divide that number by `h`, you can get imprecise results.

Comment: Actually, subtracting two almost-equal numbers has zero error (presuming IEEE 754). The result of subtracting two almost-equal numbers has the same precision as the inputs (same number of bits in its significand) and the same error (the difference from the ideal mathematical value). The **only** thing that changes is the **relative error**, and that changes only because you changed what you are measuring relative to (the result of the subtraction instead of the inputs).

Comment: A better way to view the problem with numerical differentiation is that is that the precision of f(x) and f(x+h) is insufficient to contain much information about the difference between them when h is small. The information is **already lost** when f(x) and f(x+h) are calculated. The subtraction is not the problem; no information is lost in the subtraction.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, it sounds like you're itching to leave your own answer and I invite you to do so. I tried to frame the problem in the simplest possible terms, and other viewpoints are welcome. Edit: I see  you took my suggestion even before I made it!